# Is it possible to automate NetlifyCMS to bookmark websites?

Tags: automation, netlify, hugo, netlify-cms, jamstack

I use a **Hugo on Netlify with NetlifyCMS** to bookmark websites. But every time I want to do that I need to make it by hand and then publish. Is there any way to automate this?

**How would you go about if you want to do make it? Maybe browser extension?**

[image: NetlifyCMS view1]

Answer (score 1):

NetlifyCMS just pushes text to a git repository.

I'd recommend not using NetlifyCMS for this, but instead just parsing the webpage to make the text file and commit it via git.

You could do this via a command-line script, or a backend-server, which could allow connection to a chrome extension.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, will to work it out in the weekend!